# How do I get a React dropdown menu to focus on keydown

Tags: reactjs, dropdown, wai-aria

I'm working on the behaviour of a React dropdown with ARIA support and I'm trying to get the keydown event to focus on the related menu list. Currently, when a keydown event happens, the entire document moves downwards. The behaviour I want is this:

1. Click dropdown button
2. Focus on first item in list on keydown
3. Move to next item in list based on keyup or keydown.

The entire page is scrollable and so is the dropdown list, however when I trigger a keydown event, it moves the entire page instead.

Is someone able to provide some insight into how I'm suppose to support the behaviour I want and how I go about achieving this? Am I suppose to handle the keydown event myself? If so how do I go about focusing the right div?

Current code:

```
    <div id="dd-wrapper" ref={wrapper} className="dropdown" style={{ position: 'relative' }} onClick={onClick} >
      <button
        id="dd-button"
        className="dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle--shadow background-white pt-2 pr-3 pb-2 pl-3"
        type="button"
        data-toggle="dropdown"
        aria-haspopup="true"
        aria-labelledby="dd-label dd-button"
        aria-expanded={isOpen}
      >
        <p className="dropdown-toggle--text text-large text-left m-0">
          <strong>$29</strong>
        </p>
      </button>
        <ul
          className={`dropdown-menu list-style-none pl-0 mt-0 mb-0 ${!isOpen && 'hidden'} ${isPoppedTop && 'dropdown-menu--poptop'}`}
          aria-labelledby="dd-button"
          tabIndex={isOpen ? 0 : -1}
          role="listbox"
          ref={optionEl}
        >
          {staticData.map(option => (
            <li id={`dd-${option}`} role="option" key={option} className="dropdown-item pl-0 pt-2">
              <p className="pl-3 m-0">{option}</p>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: perhaps you could create a working example using codesandbox / codepen / jsfiddle?  It would make it easier to distill the problem into a clear solution.

Comment: Good idea @SethLutske